# Zooming and details in chart with Ionic (2.x/3.x)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, charts, ionic2, bar-chart

I'm developing an mobile app, with Ionic 3 (and angular 4), and I need to do some charts. Um, it seems to be bar charts, as in the picture below. But I need a barchart per hour, and with a zoom. When the user zooms in, I should show the times in more detail.

Can someone help me with how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use highCHarts:

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-v.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    // create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [[
                    'week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                ]]
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, I'll test it. But, do you know if I can install it in my project with npm?

Comment: npm install highcharts --save